# How to achieve better clustering for indoor map on mapbox?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, mapbox, markerclusterer

I am using some default mapbox clustering, which is not enough for indoor map of building. Here is my example

```
                map.addSource('maintenance_events_on_map', {
                    type: 'geojson',
                    cluster: true,
                    clusterMaxZoom: 22, // Max zoom to cluster points on
                    clusterRadius: 1, // Radius
                    data: JSON.parse(maintenance_events_on_map)

                }).addLayer({
                    id: 'clusters',
                    type: 'circle',
                    source: 'maintenance_events_on_map',
                    paint: {
                        'circle-radius': 20,
                        'circle-color': '#973901'
                    }
                  }).addLayer({
                    id: 'cluster-label',
                    type:'symbol',
                    source:'maintenance_events_on_map',
                    layout:{
                        'text-field': "{point_count}"
                    }
                  });
```

The output is following:
[image]
I need it to be on the level of indoor building:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way achieving this is using Mapbox Studio, where you can upload custom icons, which easily can be called in the layer properties, while creating a layer. These icons are clusterable and this works much more better.